# Cannot see any native AdMob ads while doing mediation with MoPub

Tags: android, admob, ads, mopub

I want to use MoPub for mediation for Facebook Ads and Admob. I followed MoPub guides for this: [Native Ads Integration](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Native-Ads-Integration) and [Integrating Native Third Party Ad Networks](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Integrating-Native-Third-Party-Ad-Networks). Here is the code I create renderer for Admob and how I register it to MoPub ad adapter:

```
final GooglePlayServicesAdRenderer googlePlayServicesAdRenderer = new GooglePlayServicesAdRenderer(
        new ViewBinder.Builder(R.layout.native_ad_list_item)
                .titleId(R.id.native_title)
                .textId(R.id.native_text)
                .mainImageId(R.id.native_main_image)
                .iconImageId(R.id.native_icon_image)
                .callToActionId(R.id.native_cta)
                .privacyInformationIconImageId(R.id.native_privacy_information_icon_image)
                    .build());
...

MoPubNativeAdPositioning.MoPubServerPositioning adPositioning =
            MoPubNativeAdPositioning.serverPositioning();
moPubAdAdapter = new MoPubAdAdapter(getActivity(), normalArrayAdapter, adPositioning);
// moPubAdAdapter.registerAdRenderer(facebookAdRenderer);
moPubAdAdapter.registerAdRenderer(googlePlayServicesAdRenderer);
moPubAdAdapter.registerAdRenderer(moPubStaticNativeAdRenderer);
listView.setAdapter(moPubAdAdapter);
```

The `R.layout.native_ad_list_item` is copied from [here](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/blob/master/mopub-sample/res/layout/native_ad_list_item.xml). I load ads in `onResume()` as told in guides above as follows:

```
moPubAdAdapter.loadAds(getString(R.string.mopub_native_ad_unit_id));
```

My problem is that if I register `googlePlayServicesAdRenderer` only, I get no ads. If I combine it with `moPubStaticNativeAdRenderer`, I get Facebook ads, although I didn't register `facebookAdRenderer`. I also get no log about Admob ads. What could be the case?

Comment: Can you attach your device log? Check to see if the custom event class for Google (com.mopub.nativeads.GooglePlayServicesNative) is called. On the MoPub UI, make sure you are also *not* mapping your ad unit ID to a Facebook placement ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdMob Native Ad Advanced is required for MoPub mediation but we have Native Ad Express. You should contact Google to be added to those who can create advanced ads from AdMob console.